# Android RelativeLayout -- how to position?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want a Layout like this:
[image: Desired layout]

But my code doesn't work. I can't achieve this Layout, and I don't know what is wrong with what I've done so far.

Here's what I have so far -- Is the layout_gravity OK? Or does it need to be set it in the `RelativeLayout`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout     
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/topText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:layout_gravity="top" />

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/centerLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@id/topText">     

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/lektionBackButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:src="@drawable/back"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>  
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/centerImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            <ImageButton 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lektionForwardButton"
                android:src="@drawable/forward"
                android:layout_gravity="right"/>        
         </LinearLayout>    

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottomText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:layout_below="@id/centerLayout"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: nice question with perfect snap.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need to use gravity or the inner `LinearLayout` at all for this. Instead use `layout_alignParentTop`, `layout_alignParentLeft`, `layout_alignParentRight`, `layout_alignParentBottom`, `layout_centerInParent` and `layout_centerVertical` on the children.

It might be useful for you to go through the [RelativeLayout tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html).

Answer (score 3):

Only when it comes to a Relative layout, you can switch to the Graphical layout in your Eclipse editor and drag and set the attributes. Everything with just your mouse. This however isn't possible with any other layout. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -3):

`RelativeLayout` is a `ViewGroup` that displays child views in relative positions. The position of each view can be specified as relative to sibling elements (such as to the left-of or below another view) or in positions relative to the parent `RelativeLayout` area (such as aligned to the bottom, left or center).

Official [Android Developer Click.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative)

[RelativeLayout Video link.](https://youtu.be/yj-RZMPUuJ4)